# Help updates to match recent close update

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, help-center

It seems to me that if the goal of the close text is to improve the questions to the point where they can be answered and benefit the site, then the help texts could be improved.

Example: [How to do statistical analysis that include 2 levels of repeatedness in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758645)

The asker understands that SO is a programming site, but doesn't understand that the zeroth question ("how do I start?", with zero code) is off-topic. There is a link labelled "learn more" on the new blue box, but I don't think the text it points to will help the asker understand the problem.

- The help text is general and shared by all close reasons. I think closing is a big enough part of the site to warrant a "help" page for each reason, tailored to the typical misunderstandings that lead to *that* close, without digressing into the others.
- The help text hasn't been updated with the new (wording for the) close reasons.
- Last but not least, it doesn't seem likely to get the point across. In this case: "Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking." Well, I could tell what the asker asked about. The phrasing makes it sound as if the respondents were misunderstanding on purpose, just to be unfriendly and show the asker who's the master.

Comment: The example question is closed as "Too Broad", not "Unclear"

Comment: It's closed as "Need more focus", not "Too broad" or "Unclear". If I misunderstood which point on the [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) page is relevant, then I think the learn more page is to blame, not me.

Comment: Not when I look at it...but there is A/B testing of new Close Notices at the moment

Comment: "Need more focus" is just the new version of "too broad", no need to fight about that. It is still the same close reason.

Comment: Oh, I thought the A/B test had ended when I suddenly started seeing the new blue stuff. Maybe they just changed the A/B user sets.

Comment: I saw [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/24656661) just now. It'll be closed, the asker will see a "learn more" link, will click it, and will see a page where *not one word* is about what he/she wants to learn more about. Except perhaps the headline. Many informative but irrelevant sentences. Sigh. I think this is a major reason why so many people think Stack Overflow is unfriendly.